# Roots of the equation $(x^2+3x+4)^2+3(x^2+3x+4)+4=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The equation $(x^2+3x+4)^2+3(x^2+3x+4)+4=x$ has

(A) all its solution real but not all positive

(B) only two of its solution real

(C) two of its solution positive and two negative

(D) none of its solution real

My approach is as follow $(x^2+3x+4)^2+3(x^2+3x+4)+4-x=y$

$f(x)=y=x^4+6x^3+20x^2+32x+32$

$f(-x)=y=x^4-6x^3+20x^2-32x+32$

Using Descartes rule no positive roots but the possible ways we can have either 4,2,0 negative roots.

$f'(x)=4x^3+18x^2+40x+32$

$f''(x)=12x^2+36x+40$ which is imaginary

From here I am not able to approach.

Comment: Somehow I feel like there should be an easier way! Notice how the expressions in parentheses are the same? Perhaps you can take a variable change, like $t=x^2+3x+4$ ...

Comment: $f''(x)$ is not "imaginary", the roots of this function are non-real.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t=x^2+2x+4$, then we can write the equation as:

$$(t+x)^2+3(t+x)+4-x=0$$

or

$$t^2+2tx+x^2+3t+2x+4=0$$

or

$$t^2+2tx+3t+t=0$$

or

$$t(t+2x+4)=0$$

so

$$(x^2+2x+4)(x^2+4x+8)=0$$

Can you end it now?

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks +1

Comment: Nice (also +1) , but I prefer the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

Hint (edited): Let $f(x) = x^2+3x+4$. Then $f(x) > x $ for all reals $x$, hence $f(f(x)) > f(x) > x$ for all reals $x$.

Comment: Very nice solution! (+1)

Comment: By "same real solutions", I believe you mean that there are no real solutions for either, in this case?

Comment: I think he wants to say $f(f(x))>f(x)>x$

Comment: @GoodDeeds: yes; I've edited the solution for clarity.

Comment: I find this approach even more elegant.

Comment: This answer would have deserved an accept.

Comment: This is the very definition of elegance!

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2+3x+4)^2+3(x^2+3x+4)+4=x$$
$$(x^2+3x+4)^2+4(x^2+3x+4)+4=x+x^2+3x+4$$
$$(x^2+3x+4+2)^2=(x+2)^2$$
$$(x^2+3x+6)^2-(x+2)^2=0$$
then use the fact
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f(x)=(x^2+3x+4)^2+3(x^2+3x+4)+4-x$

$\displaystyle f(x)=\bigg[\bigg(x+\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^2+\frac{7}{4}\bigg]^2+3\bigg[\bigg(x+\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^2+\frac{7}{4}\bigg]+4-x$

put $\displaystyle x+\frac{3}{2}=t\in \mathbb{R}$

$\displaystyle f(t)=\bigg(t^2+\frac{7}{4}\bigg)^2+3\bigg(t^2+\frac{7}{4}\bigg)+4-t+\frac{3}{2}$

$\displaystyle f(t)=t^4+\frac{49}{16}+\frac{7}{2}t^2+3t^2+\frac{21}{4}+4+\frac{3}{2}-t$

$\displaystyle f(t)=t^4+\frac{13}{2}\bigg[t^2-\frac{2}{13}t+\frac{1}{13^2}+\frac{43}{26}-\frac{1}{13^2}\bigg]$

$\displaystyle f(t)=t^4+\frac{13}{2}\bigg[\bigg(t-\frac{1}{13}\bigg)^2+\frac{43\cdot 13-2}{26\cdot 13}\bigg]>0$